# R.java file is vanish after clean my project

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm working on my project in eclipse , but after adding some files I clean my project, but after clean the R.java file automatically vanish from my project & lots of error on my project.

again I tried to clean my & build it but my R.java files can't back.

What I'll do at this moment?

Comment: Because there was an error in your project before cleaning. Error can be in importing external libraries or in some resource files. Check and correct it and then again clean your project. Surely it will work.

Comment: Check for errors in your XML files. If there's an error there, R.java will not be generated by aapt.

Comment: Other possible causes: **Upper Case Characters** in your resource file names; **Invalid Characters** in your resource file names (you can use only `a...z`, `0...9` (not as first character), `.` and `_`); File names **starting with a number** ...

Comment: Thank you guyer. My problem is solved After few min Posting here by fuxing the error  of xml file then again clean my projec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if R.java is not being automatically created then there is an error somewhere in your xml. Triple check everything.

Check your XML resources (especially these recently edited) for mistakes and sytax errors. When you have an error inside one of these files, the R class autogeneration will abort.

**surely you have error in XML.**

**edit:**

Other possible causes: Upper Case Characters in your resource file names; Invalid Characters in your resource file names (you can use only a...z, 0...9 (not as first character), . and _); File names starting with a number

thanks to Der Golem