# How to can I make certain fields appear in R file?

Tags: android

I have these pieces of code:

```
btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);
ipfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipfield);
portfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.portfield);
```

and

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

It gives me these errors:

> buttonstart cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> buttonstop cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> ipfield cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> portfield cannot be resolved or is not a field
>
> xml cannot be resolved or is not a field

So I went into R to see if I can find them and they aren't there. I tried setting them manually, but I still get errors. I cleaned the project multiple times and R still didn't generate them.

These are my imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

Button btnStart, btnStop;
EditText ipfield, portfield;
```

Comment: why are you doing `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` is it a settings activity?

Comment: You are doing something wrong and asking question to not include certain fields in R.Java file. Please asked question properly.

Comment: you may have error in xml files. this is the reason for R file not generating.

My personal suggestion - Please jump into Android studio.

refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284292/3879847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have not declare the ID in the xml file where you have define your Buttons and EditTexts.
You have to declare it with (for example):

```
android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try using [your package name].R to reference your views, also make sure that your xml files have the id attribute set like this;

```
android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
```

and so on.